# Assigning data to variables in the component so it could be used anywhere within the component in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have a function in my angular 2 project which fetches data from database through an api. I have created the following function that stores the data succesfully in the variable "**ReqData**" that has been assigned as type "***any***".

```
 this._visitService.getchartData().subscribe(data =>
{ this.ReqData = data
  console.log("ISubscribe", this.ReqData );

});
console.log("OSubscribe", this.ReqData );
this.ImpoData = this.getData( this.ReqData);
```

But the problem is although that the data can be successfully passed on within the subscribe, calling the value outside of the subscribe gives out the output **undefined**. Is there a way to get to use the data outside the subscribe too.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, `this.ReqData` is already accessible everywhere in the component. But you just need to make sure that you call it only after that the code inside subscribe has been called, which is when `this._visitService.getchartData()` has retrieved the data. This is because the code inside subscribe will be executed asynchronously.

If you want to use the value straight after, just do it in the subscribe block

```
 this._visitService.getchartData().subscribe(data =>
{ this.ReqData = data
  console.log("ISubscribe", this.ReqData );
  this.ImpoData = this.getData( this.ReqData);

});
//Here this.ReqData is not defined
```

**Edit**: If you really want to use that value outside of the subscribeblock, you can convert the observable to a promise and use the await/async pattern

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

//...
async yourMethod()
{
    try
    {
        this.ReqData = await this._visitService.getchartData().toPromise();
        //Here this.ReqData is accessible
        this.ImpoData = this.getData( this.ReqData);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        //Handle your error here
    }


}
```

Comment: `this.ReqData` doesnot get called from the front end `this._visitService.getchartData()` gets executed on its own when the page loads and the console prints the expected data but the same does not work for the console.log called outside.

Comment: that solution is something i figured out earlier but i am looking for a way to use it outside the subscribe. It must be possible right?

Comment: convert the observable to Promise and use async await if you need it right aafter. I'll edit my answer

Comment: i dint quite get it can you depict it in code? i am really new to angular

Comment: I cannot use parameter in 'this.getData()' method but i need to use the value stored in `this.reqData` to be used inside the 'this.getData()` method.

Comment: @AtulStha I was just using the example you provided in your question. But it does not change anything, wether you pass `this.ReqData` as parameter or use it directly in `this.getData`: it WILL be available globally in the class right after the call to `await this._visit...`

Comment: Its not possible as changing the function into async stops the program from working. I am trying to integrate amCharts which recives data from `getData()`. Including async stops the chart from loading.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608661/how-to-get-value-outside-subscribe-in-angular2 can you visit this

Comment: On which method did you set the async keywork? And you need to show where getData is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168187/discussion-between-atul-stha-and-david).